# How can i transfer 12 V, 50 Hz, 1 A wirelessly?

Tags: power-supply, circuit-analysis, circuit-design, 12v

I want to transfer electical power wirelessly from a transmitter to a receiver coil.

Input energy is provided by a single phase step-down transformer - 230V/12V AC, 50 Hz, 1,000 mA.

Using the 12 V AC output I want to transfer as much of the available power wirelessly from transmitter coil to the receiver coil over a distance of 5mm. 
How can that be done ?
What calculations should i solve so as to achieve this ?

I want to transmit across 5 millimeters.
The radii of the transmitter and receiver coils I am currently using are are 5cm and 2cm respectively

After transmitting it to the receiver coil, I wish to rectify and filter it and then regulate it to 5V DC use it to charge a battery.

I want 5V DC at the end of the circuit, but how can I accomplish that ?

What calculations and equipment specifications do I have to use so that I can figure this out?

Comment: Across how much distance? And how much space do you have available for transmitting and receiving devices?

Comment: I edited your title to match the requirements stated in your text. If you really wanted the system to be both 50 Hz and 1000 Hz, we can discuss why that doesn't make sense.

Comment: https://www.hindawi.com/journals/jece/2014/906537/

Comment: You do not specify how far you want to transmit the energy.

Comment: The energy stored in a capacitor ----- hint, electric-field energy movement --- is 0.5 * C * Voltage^2.  You want to transfer 12 watts. At 10,000 volts, you need 0.5 * C to be 12/(10,000 * 10,000) or 1.2e-8. Thus 2.4e-8 farads needs to be charged, once per second, to 10,000 volts. Or much faster, to lower voltages. Now ---- over what distance?

Comment: Thanks. I want to transmitt across 5 millimeters. While the radii of transmitter and receiver coils are 5cm and 2cm respectively.

Comment: With the new information added, presumably all the close votes are no longer valid. At least I don't understand what's "too broad" with this question now.

Comment: Whoever the 4 vote to close people are  - If you voted to close on the now multiply edited  [**deemed-duplicate question**](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/431263/3288)  please consider altering your vote.