# How can I achieve 5V DC from 230V AC wirelessly?

Tags: power-supply, circuit-analysis, circuit-design, 12v

I want to step down 230VAC so that I can have a large amount of current that I can transmit wirelessly through the transmitter coil to the receiver coil.

I want to transmit it across 5millimetres between a transmitter and receiver.

Radii of the transmitter and receiver can be at-least 4cm and 2cm respectively.

After transmitting it to the receiver coil, I'm going to rectify it so that I can have a certain amount of DC voltage.

After rectifying the amount received, I'm going to filter it.
Then regulate it to 5V DC and feed it to the battery.

PROBLEM

I want 5V DC at the end of the circuit, but how can I accomplish that ?

What calculations and equipment specifications do I have to use so that I can figure this out?

Comment: Easiest way: get a wireless phone charger. That goes from mains (can be 230V AC) and gives you USB charging (5V) out the other end. If you want more details, look up the Qi wireless charging method. As you haven't told us the current or power you want out, there's not much more to say.

Comment: Why have you tagged this 12V?

Comment: This is a duplicate of your other question which was closed because you omitted the power requirements. You've haven't got them in this question either. You should fix the original question to have it reopened instead of asking the same question again.

Comment: Can you use an iron core to fill in that 5mm spacing? There is no wire between, but this is simply a transformer.

Comment: What research have you done so far?

Comment: This is NOT an exact duplicate of the question cited. It is the same problem but this is better presented with much more information than the other. People gave the other 4 downvotes and no answers and nobody apparently removed their downvotes, so it is likely doomed. A new attempt with a better question seems in order given the failure of the identified somewhat 'senior' members to meet their social contract downvote management responsibilities.

Comment: @bimpelrekkie - If you voted to close on the now multiply edited  [**deemed-duplicate question**](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/431263/3288)  please consider altering your vote.

Comment: @doxylover - If you voted to close on the now multiply edited  [**deemed-duplicate question**](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/431263/3288)  please consider altering your vote.

Comment: @redgrittybrick  - If you voted to close on the now multiply edited  [**deemed-duplicate question**](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/431263/3288)  please consider altering your vote.

Comment: @andy aka  - If you voted to close on the now multiply edited  [**deemed-duplicate question**](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/431263/3288)  please consider altering your vote.